# how to show Html Div after Ajax Success in Django

Tags: javascript, django, ajax, django-templates

i have Djnago App and i want message appear to the user after Ajax call Successs
here is y Messages html

```html
 <a id="added" class="btn btn-template-outlined" href="{% url 'shop:add_product' id=products.id %}">Add to cart</a>

  <p id="connt" class="text-center">
   {% if messages %}              
   {% for message in messages %}
    {{message}}
   {% endfor %}
   {% endif %}
    </p>
```

and here is my Ajax

```html
$("#added").click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({url: "{% url 'shop:add_product' id=products.id %}",
    success: function(response){
      appendToUsrTable();
    }});
  });
function appendToUsrTable() {
 ("#connt").append(`

 `)
    }
  </script>
```

Comment: Hi, what does `response` has ? can you show output of that ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about Django messages, then this cant be as the the template will rendered and returned to the user before Ajax call so at the of rendering, there will be no message.